# What if the sun was replaced by Alpha Centauri?

Tags: solar-system, binary-star, hypothetical

What would happen if the sun suddenly got replaced with the entire Alpha Centauri system? Alpha Cen A will be in the sun’s position, with Alpha Cen B not too far off into the distance. How would this mess up the solar system?

Comment: We don't normally answer impossible hypothetical questions on this site. But I must admit that I'm curious to know what this would look like, and how long it would take to stabilise. I expect that at least one of our regular members has an orbit simulator that can handle this...

Comment: Title and question are different. Which stellar system, which planets do you want to consider? The impact is different, if you get replaced by my clone or I am replaced by your clone

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, didn’t see that. I changed it.

Comment: This can be easily simulated in Universe Sandbox.

Comment: Problem is that I don’t have a computer to download it.

Comment: @PrincePugs "How would this mess up the solar system?" you mean *our* solar system, not the one(s) associated with "the entire Alpha Centauri system" correct? :-)

Comment: I've voted to close.  This kind of question really falls down because it depends on "How the sun is replaced", and since this isn't actually possible answers will tend to assume some level of magic. This can easily result in lots of low quality answers depending on just what kind of magic is assumed.

Comment: Yes, correct @uhoh